# Open a modal from an iframe in a third party site

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog

I will have a simple page with a video and some FAQ (hosted my end), but I want several websites to click a button in a supplied iframe that will launch my content into a modal on there site. Is this fairly straightforward to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write JavaScript on both pages and use the PostMessage API to communicate between the two.

Comment: As I'll not have access to add any javascript to the other websites I guess it's not a route I can take.